# What are the uses of tf.space_to_depth?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am reading this document on [`tf.space_to_depth`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth). There, it says about the use of the function:

> This operation is useful for resizing the activations between
>   convolutions (but keeping all data), e.g. instead of pooling. It is
>   also useful for training purely convolutional models.

However, I still don't get a clear understanding of this. Why is it sometimes necessary to resize the activations in a model?

Comment: Still not clear about  resizing the activations between convolutions, why do people have to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

`space_to_depth` is a convolutional practice used very often for lossless spatial dimensionality reduction. Applied to tensor `(example_dim, width, height, channels)` with `block_size = k` it produces a tensor with shape `(example_dim, width / block_size, height / block_size, channels * block_size ** 2)`. It works in a following manner (`example_dim` is skipped for simplicity):

1. **Cut image / feature map into chunks of size (block_size, block_size, channels)**: e.g. the following image (with `block_size = 2`):

   ```
   [[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
    [[5], [6], [7], [8]],
    [[9], [10], [11], [12]],
    [[13], [14], [15], [16]]]
   ```

   is divided into the following chunks:

   ```
   [[[1], [2]],       [[[3], [4]],
    [[5], [6]]]        [[7], [8]]]

   [[[9], [10],]      [[[11], [12]],
    [[13], [14]]]      [[15], [16]]]
   ```
2. **Flatten each chunk to a single array**:

   ```
   [[1, 2, 5, 6]],      [[3, 4, 7, 8]]
   [[9 10, 13, 14]],    [[11, 12, 15, 16]]
   ```
3. **Spatially rearrange chunks according to their initial position:**

   ```
   [[[1, 2, 5, 6]], [[3, 4, 7, 8]],
    [[9 10, 13, 14]], [[11, 12, 15, 16]]]
   ```

So - as you may see - the initial image with size `(4, 4, 1)` was rearranged to feature map with shape `(2, 2, 4)`. The following strategy is usually used for applications like object detection, segmentation or superresolution when it's important to decrease the spatial size of an image without losing reduction (like `pooling`). An example of an application of this technique might be found e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps